# windows phone 7 app on full screen

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, screen-resolution

I started to write an app for windows phone 7, but when I test it in the emulator,there is an empty strip in the side of the screen that I can't fill. Here is the XAML of the page:

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="776*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="24*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="480*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Image Height="480" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="728" Source="/app;component/Background.jpg" />
        <MediaElement Height="0" Name="mediaElement1" Width="1" Volume="1" Source="Kalimba.mp3" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Image Grid.Row="1" Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,164,0,0" Name="image2" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Source="/app;component/Easy_Button_Normal.png" />
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="468,164,0,0" Name="image3" Source="/app;component/Hard_Button_Normal.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" />
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Height="51" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="272,164,0,0" Name="image4" Source="/app;component/Medium_Button_Normal.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" />
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Height="118" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="286,362,0,0" Name="image5" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148" Source="/app;component/Play_Button_Normal.png" />
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,122,0,0" Name="image6" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="238" Source="/app;component/Headline.png" />
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="620,426,0,0" Name="image7" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="32" Source="/app;component/Play_Button.png" Tap="image7_Tap" />
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="58,426,0,0" Name="image8" Source="/app;component/Scores_Button.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="32" Tap="image8_Tap" />
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
</Grid>

<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no "Fullscreen" concept on the phone. Simply change the control so that it takes up the whole screen.**

**You could do this explicitly or, if you have size set to auto, just hide all other items on the screen.**

All differences between Windows Phone 7 and Windows phone 8 screen-size (resolution) are explain [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). (in the MSDN websites, with samples).

On windows phone, you must manage all screen resolutions... If you have a project Windows Phone 7 by default, your screen size is adapted to this project and you are on WVGA (480 * 800). And, if you don't manage all size screen, on the Windows Phone device (or emulator) in 720p, you are a part of black screen on the top of your applications.

**`For informations: Windows Phone 7 devices just manage`**

- the WVGA resolution (480*800)

**`Windows Phone 8 devices manage three screen sizes:`**

- the WVGA resolution (480*800)
- the WXGA resolution (768 × 1280)
- the 720p resolution (720 × 1280)
  // rumors Part

And, Maybe with Windows phone 8 and GDR3 update, Windows Phone 8 manage one additional screen size

- the 1080p resolution (1080*1920)
  // End rumors part

Be sure there is the Attribute in

```
<phone:phoneApplicationPage shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
```

which must be set to false for the full screen show.

Comment: What I was looking for is the IsVisible property. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting two columns in your grid, but you are using only one. Try by removing the column definitions:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="776*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="24*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```